# Web api not returning json while consuming in client

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have created a web api and i am consuming it by clinet but my web api is returning wrong format instead of JSON.

**WEB API code**

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, todoService.GetData());
}
```

**CODE for consuming web api**

```
client = new HttpClient();
string RestUrl = "http://test.com/";        
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RestUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/TodoItems/Get").Result;
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var uri = new Uri(string.Format(RestUrl, string.Empty));
```

**OUTput that i am getting**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Client Validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) {
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + expiredays) + ";path=/";
}
function getHostUri() {
            var loc = document.location;
                    return loc.toString();
}
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+1);
setCookie('DOAAuthReferrer', document.referrer, exdate.toUTCString());
setCookie('DOADFgsjnrSFgsg329gaFGa3ggs9434sgSGS43tsgSHSG35', '#392fc2a39a8bf6848e4f5e7551888a6d8a9db50a#FFWW#1466187439#794189797#', 'Fri, 17 Jun 2016 18:17:19 GMT');
try {  
    location.reload(true);  
} catch (err1) {  
    try {  
        location.reload();  
    } catch (err2) {  
        location.href = getHostUri();  
    }  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

BUT i want to get json while consuming instead of above output..Please let me know what should i do???????

Comment: When you try to access the endpoint in a browser, are you getting the json data ?

Comment: Probably an issue with your routing. Can u add all the routes here?

Comment: what you have in BuildSuccessResult?

Comment: @Shyju yes i am able to see the JSON perfect

Comment: @AlekseyL. in BuildSuccessResult it shows 'OK'

Comment: @ParvSharma its default routing that i have used no extra route added

Comment: can you post the code of "BuildSuccessResult"?